# C++ - Windows Shell API - How to write/modify the content of a file

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

Consider the following code:

```cpp
bool OpenStream(const std::wstring& fileName)
{
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = nullptr;

    if (FAILED(::SHILCreateFromPath(fileName.c_str(), &pidl, nullptr)))
        return false;

    wchar_t buffer[MAX_PATH + 1];

    if (::SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidl, buffer))
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"File IDL path: ");
        ::OutputDebugString(buffer);
        ::OutputDebugString(L"\r\n");
    }

    IShellFolder* pShellfolder = nullptr;
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlRelative = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = ::SHBindToParent(pidl, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)&pShellfolder, &pidlRelative);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        return false;
    }

    if (::SHGetPathFromIDListW(pidl, buffer))
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(L"Relative IDL path: ");
        ::OutputDebugString(buffer);
        ::OutputDebugString(L"\r\n");
    }

    IStream* pStream = nullptr;

    //if (FAILED(pShellfolder->BindToObject(pidlRelative, NULL, IID_IStream, (void**)&pStream)))
    if (FAILED(pShellfolder->BindToStorage(pidlRelative, NULL, IID_IStream, (void**)&pStream)))
    {
        pShellfolder->Release();
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        return false;
    }

    ULARGE_INTEGER size;
    ::IStream_Size(pStream, &size);

    LARGE_INTEGER pos = {0};

    pStream->Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr);

    unsigned char* pBuffer = new unsigned char[size.QuadPart];

    ULONG actualRead;
    hr = pStream->Read(pBuffer, size.QuadPart, &actualRead);

    std::FILE* pFile;
    fopen_s(&pFile, "__Copy.bin", "wb");

    if (!pFile)
    {
        delete[] pBuffer;
        pShellfolder->Release();
        ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
        return false;
    }

    const std::size_t writeCount = std::fwrite(pBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), size.QuadPart, pFile);

    std::fclose(pFile);
    delete[] pBuffer;

    pStream->Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, nullptr);

    hr = pStream->Write("Test-test-test-test", 19, nullptr);

    pShellfolder->Release();
    ::CoTaskMemFree(pidl);

    return true;
}
```

This code opens the file passed in `fileName` in a stream and write its content in a new file, using the std to achieve that. Until here all works fine.

However, as a last operation, I want to modify the content of the opened file. However I cannot do that with the above code, indeed it compiles and runs, but it does nothing, and I receive an **ACCESS_DENIED** error as a result.

How should I modify the above code to allow the opened stream to read **AND WRITE** in my file?

Also, as a side question: Is the above code safe and well written (i.e will it generates memory leaks, or is something unsafe in it)? A detailed review would be welcome.

Comment: Why not just open the file directly?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I believe the Shell API can open a stream on a great number of shell namespace entities that aren't traditional files.  Using it on a traditional file seems like a good first step in learning to use it to manipulate other shell namespace entities.

Comment: @BenVoigt That makes sense, if this is a learning exercise to expand to non-files. But if all you care about is files, you may as well just go straight to SHCreateStreamOnFile.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you're implicitly opening the stream as read-only. To open it for write operations, you must pass a [binding context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-ibindctx), something like this:

```
IBindCtx* ctx;
CreateBindCtx(0, &ctx);

BIND_OPTS options = {};
options.cbStruct = sizeof(BIND_OPTS);
options.grfMode = STGM_WRITE;
ctx->SetBindOptions(&options);

...
pShellfolder->BindToStorage(pidlRelative, ctx, IID_IStream, (void**)&pStream);
...
```

Otherwise, when you work with COM objects, you should smart pointers to avoid COM reference leaks. For example, below, I use [ATL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/smart-pointers-modern-cpp) that comes with Visual Studio, but there's also [WRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl) and C++/WinRT (which can do some basic COM stuff too)

Also, for Shell objects it's much easier to work with [IShellItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellitem) and friends and all ("Item") APIs that come with it, like this (error checks omitted here but you should test every single HRESULT for error) and avoid the old `IShellFolder`:

```
CComPtr<IShellItem> item;
SHCreateItemFromParsingName(fileName.c_str(), nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&item));

CComPtr<IBindCtx> ctx;
CreateBindCtx(0, &ctx);

BIND_OPTS options = {};
options.cbStruct = sizeof(BIND_OPTS);
options.grfMode = STGM_WRITE;
ctx->SetBindOptions(&options);

CComPtr<IStream> stream;
item->BindToHandler(ctx, BHID_Stream, IID_PPV_ARGS(&stream));

stream->Write("Test-test-test-test", 19, nullptr);
```